# Ist it possible to assign a random time to camunda intermediate timer catch event?

Tags: groovy, camunda, bpmn

In my camunda process i want use a timer catch event to wait a random duration between 5-15 seconds. Is it possible to assign this random duration to the event?

Comment: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/modeler/bpmn/timer-events/#timers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script task of type *javascirpt* to generate the value like:

```
"PT" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 +5) + "S";
```

and store it in a result process data. Subsequently reference the data in the time expression like:

```
#{timer}
```

Example Model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <bpmn:definitions 
            xmlns:bpmn="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="Definitions_0fr9mxs" targetNamespace="http://bpmn.io/schema/bpmn" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="5.1.0">
  <bpmn:process id="ExampleprocessProcess" name="example-process" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn:endEvent id="EndEvent_0x6ir2l">
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_09qj0b7</bpmn:incoming>
    </bpmn:endEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_09qj0b7" sourceRef="Event_18ugk9p" targetRef="EndEvent_0x6ir2l" />
    <bpmn:intermediateCatchEvent id="Event_18ugk9p">
      <bpmn:extensionElements />
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_16gzt2m</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_09qj0b7</bpmn:outgoing>
      <bpmn:timerEventDefinition id="TimerEventDefinition_0shqn5w">
        <bpmn:timeDuration xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">#{timer}</bpmn:timeDuration>
      </bpmn:timerEventDefinition>
    </bpmn:intermediateCatchEvent>
    <bpmn:scriptTask id="CreateRandomTimeTask" name="create random time" scriptFormat="javascript" camunda:resultVariable="timer">
      <bpmn:extensionElements />
      <bpmn:incoming>Flow_1x8rlyg</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_16gzt2m</bpmn:outgoing>
      <bpmn:script>"PT" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 11 +5) + "S";</bpmn:script>
    </bpmn:scriptTask>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_16gzt2m" sourceRef="CreateRandomTimeTask" targetRef="Event_18ugk9p" />
    <bpmn:startEvent id="Event_0luae7f">
      <bpmn:outgoing>Flow_1x8rlyg</bpmn:outgoing>
    </bpmn:startEvent>
    <bpmn:sequenceFlow id="Flow_1x8rlyg" sourceRef="Event_0luae7f" targetRef="CreateRandomTimeTask" />
  </bpmn:process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="ExampleprocessProcess">
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="SequenceFlow_16gzt2m_di" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_16gzt2m">
        <di:waypoint x="370" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="432" y="117" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_09qj0b7_di" bpmnElement="Flow_09qj0b7">
        <di:waypoint x="468" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="522" y="117" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_1x8rlyg_di" bpmnElement="Flow_1x8rlyg">
        <di:waypoint x="188" y="117" />
        <di:waypoint x="270" y="117" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_07yj7bl_di" bpmnElement="Event_18ugk9p">
        <dc:Bounds x="432" y="99" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_1ws8xyt_di" bpmnElement="CreateRandomTimeTask">
        <dc:Bounds x="270" y="77" width="100" height="80" />
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_0luae7f_di" bpmnElement="Event_0luae7f">
        <dc:Bounds x="152" y="99" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="EndEvent_0x6ir2l_di" bpmnElement="EndEvent_0x6ir2l">
        <dc:Bounds x="522" y="99" width="36" height="36" />
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn:definitions>
```

Comment: please reformat xml